# combine background image with background gradient

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

is it possible to combine a background image with a background gradient? How can you add this via jQuery to another div?

My code looks like this...

```
$('#cboxTitle').css({
background-image: 'url(images/login.png)',
background-image: '-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#1f344b), to(#132533))',
background-image: '-webkit-linear-gradient(#1f344b, #132533)',
background-image: '-moz-linear-gradient(#1f344b, #132533)',
background-image: '-ms-linear-gradient(#1f344b, #132533)',
background-image: '-o-linear-gradient(#1f344b, #132533)',
background-image: 'linear-gradient(#1f344b, #132533)'
});
```

...but it doesn't work.:(

Additionally I want to add the styles via jQuery to another div (id="cboxTitle"). How do you do this? Is this cross-browser compatible (including old Internet Explorer versions)?

Comment: It's possible with multiple backgrounds `background-image: url(..),linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #000)`. Why jQuery? Use a class an toggle it it'll be easier.

Comment: A jQuery solution would be better in my case because my website uses it heavily. I have to change it via jQuery because the divs get loaded via a plugin (colorbox).

Comment: That's a jQuery solution, you use CSS to style the element how you need and jQuery to toggle the class on and off.

Comment: Ah!! Ok. I don't have that much experience with jQuery, yet. Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

http://jsfiddle.net/Dku2D/

I have added extra css for height and width of button.

```
#mybutton {
background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#1f344b), to(rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53))), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1f344b, rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53)), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1f344b, rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53)), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1f344b, rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53)), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#1f344b, rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53)), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
background: linear-gradient(#1f344b, rgba(19, 37, 51, 0.53)), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yu may use `div` inside of a `div`. The first one will have gradient background, and the second one your bg image.

And you can add CSS properties by jQuery's `.css()` http://api.jquery.com/css/ (it'd be something like `$('#cboxTitle').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 2):

as already said, you should use CSS3's multiple backgrounds feature:

```
background-image: url(…), -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#FFF), to(#000));
background-image: url(…), -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);
```

to support this in older browsers just use http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Nice hint!:) Didn't know modernzr.com so far. Thank you very much!:)